# Nextjs with MUI in the APP router foloder structure

Tags: next.js13

here getting flickering issue with mui textfield standard in nextjs app folder. How to resolve any idea. So here just you create an new project for the nextjs and mui ,In the mui take the basictextfileds component of the standard variant and check there will be a flickering issue getting. can u check the image whats happening in this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fkA7L.png)